# Link not clickable with transition hover effect

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I'm working on a portfolio site and want portfolio pieces to have a fancy rollover.

I've made a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/txinG) of what I have so far. My issue is that the Visit Site link isn't clickable. I have no idea why, but I think it may be something to do with the z-index change or the transition effect. It was working before when I used a simple slide-up over the image effect.

Any ideas how to get this link clickable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add

`backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;`

to `.default-view` and it works :)